# Python while loop continues even when false (even if variable declared global)

Tags: python, debugging

I have a while loop in python that won't stop when false, but unlike other questions, I encountered on stack overflow, I declared my global variable.

```
import random

score = 0
health = 75
maxhealth = 100
keys = 0
health_potions = 0
skip_stage = 1
cmd = ""
inc = 0

def hiahelp():
    #code
def stats():
    #code
def oCmds():
    global cmd
    global inc
    global health
    if cmd == "stats":
        stats()
        inc = 0
    elif cmd == "help":
        hiahelp()
        inc = 0
    elif cmd == "use health potion":
        #healing code
    elif cmd == "use":
        print("incomplete command")
    else:
        inc = 1

#intro code

while health > 0:

#more intro code

    print("What is HungryIronApple's favorite music artist (besides himself, include proper capitalization)?")
    def stage1():
        r = True
        while r:
            global inc
            global cmd
            global health
            if inc == 1:
                print("incorrect, try again")
                health = health - 10
            cmd = input("answer: ")
            if cmd == "Alan Walker":
                inc = 0
                r = False
            elif cmd == "left" or cmd == "right":
                print("originally I would take health away for such a dumb mistake but because we are just getting started, I'll ignore it")
            else:
                oCmds()
    stage1()
    print("the door opens")
    quit()
print(f"you died {username}")
```

I expected it to stop when I die but it continues asking for answers.
Can someone please explain this?
please note I hardly use tag comments and that they are just substitutions.
Below is an example of the running code:
[image: running the code]

Comment: Can't see where `inc` comes from but it never changes in the `while` loop so, if it's not `1`, health will never decrease

Comment: Declaring a variable as global in python is very rare.  Are you sure you need to do that?  Can you print health as the first line under the while statement and see if the vale is decreasing as expected?

Comment: when incorrect, `inc` changes to 1 from 0

Comment: why is the `global` call inside a loop ? and where is the function definition ?

Comment: simply use `print()` inside loop to display values in variables and you will see problem.

Comment: This code isn't valid, it's a syntax error to use a variable an then later declare it as global. Please show your actual code.

Comment: health changes according to my stat command

Comment: We still need to see a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) portion of code. The code as written fails with a `SyntaxError: name 'inc' is assigned to before global declaration` error, and, even if it didn't, it would not demonstrate the behaviour you have just posted.

Comment: I can't paste the whole code, it says my post is mostly code

Comment: You don't need to post everything. You need to post just enough code that runs and demonstrates your problem as you are experiencing it. Currently the code you've posted does neither.

Comment: I think that is enough code for now

Comment: oh shoot, i deleted the while loop

Comment: You have now shown us an inner `while r:` loop. `r` is always True regardless of health. It never stops until you enter the correct answer, because control never returns to the `while health > 0:` if `r` is True

Comment: man aren't I glad people are complaining to help me rather than dislike to confuse me, I'm just barely old enough to use social media

Comment: gonna try embedding the health scenario inside the while loop as well

Comment: it stopped but instead of loosing, it won

Comment: ok fixed, I completely abolished the while health statement and added if statements at the end

Comment: There's too much really to post an 'answer' so I will just add a couple of comments. In the sample posted, you had global statements and function definitions inside loops. Don't do that... do all that before the loop. The much better solution, but it might be too soon, would be to learn how to define a class so that your functions are  defined within the class so they can access the class variables without having to call global all over the place. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is constrained by values of `health`. The only time `health` changes within your loop is if `inc == 1`.

Given your code snippet, it's impossible to say if `inc` ever changes within your loop (I do see `#more code` so I'm guessing there's something in there?). Since it starts at 0 and never changes, then `health` will never change also.

To debug this, take a look at values of `inc` and `health` and track their change over time. It may also help you to temporarily change the iteration of `while health > 0` to `for x in range(100)` so that you constrain the repetition and can debug patterns in the change in values for `health` and `inc`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious that `inc` is set to `0`, and then `health` doesn't get modified at all.

Thus, the `while` loop condition never breaks.

The `global` statement is redundant, in python a scope is limited to 3 possibilities (global, local, nonlocal).
Unlike C, where each block has its own scope.